# Node.js Writing Proxty- Url concatenates over and over

Tags: node.js

I am trying to write my own Node.js proxy. I know there are other node modules to do this, but I wanted to do it manually myself for the learning experience.

I have the below function which I plug into connect.js with `server.use()`

```
function foo(req, res, next) {
    var url = /container-templates/;
    if (url.test(req.url)) {
        res.writeHead(301, {"Location": '/staging.host/' + req.url});
        res.end();
    } else { next() }
}
```

But when it redirects, it concatenates the url in a weird fashion over and over....for example:

```
Request URL:http://10.14.23.61:9000/staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//staging.host//container-templates/allIds
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if you have it mounted using just `server.use()` then this gets fired on every request, so on every request it does the logic you have there.  You need another handler with a higher precedent that responds to the first redirect and provides a response of some kind.